# Excel month formula is not working properly

Tags: excel

My formula on L2 is
`=MONTH(A2)`

On A2 I filled in 11-1-2019 and now L2 shows '1'. So that's all good.

The problem is that I need this formula from L2 to L1000. But when I copy it it automatically fills in '1', even when there is no date filled in.

Example:
My formula on L3 is
`=MONTH(A3)`

A3 is empty. But L3 still shows '1'.

What I need is that formula to be there, but only activate when I fill in the date for that specific cell. So L3 should remain empty until I fill in a date on A3.

Comment: `=IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",MONTH(A3))`?

Answer (score 2):

Try `=IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",MONTH(A3))`

Comment: I'm not sure why that wouldn't work, but you could try `=IF(A3="","",MONTH(A3))` instead.

Comment: Is there any more clarification you could provide as to the type of error? I've got both of the formulas in my spreadsheet running Excel 2016.

Comment: It says something like 'there is a problem with this formula' and this part is highlighted
,"",MONTH

Comment: I suppose it's possible that your Excel is utilizing a ; in place of a , as a paramter delimiter. I guess try `=IF(ISBLANK(A3);"";MONTH(A3))`

Comment: That was the case indeed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!